# Using mclust on data from .mat file

Tags: r, mclust

I'm new to R, and I'm trying to use the mclust package.

What I need to do is to take data from `data.mat` file and cluster it using mclust.

The code I use is:

```
data <- readMat('data.mat')
mod1 <- Mclust(data['X'], modelName='EVE')
```

And I get the following error:

> fitting ...
>    |
>    |   0%Error in mvnX(data = data, prior = prior) :
>    (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

I've tested `summary(data['X'])` and the data is numerical

> Length   Class  Mode
>   X 29000000 -none- numeric

I've tried using `as.matrix(data['X'])` and I get the same error.
I've tried different `modelName` and I get the same error.

Surely I am missing something, help me :(